# Logcat Limitations or Bug

Tags: android, android-fragments, logcat, android-logcat

I am creating a fragment with many buttons. Partially out of laziness and just to see if it is possible, I have created a several lines of code to output the nessecary code for each buttons onclick. However the logcat has been causing trouble in achieving this.

code:

```
public class practiceFinishFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

  String idss = "";
    TextView textView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.practice_finished_fragment, container, false);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.finishedLayout);
        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
for(int i = 0; layout.getChildCount() > i; i++){
            if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof Button){
                layout.getChildAt(i).setOnClickListener(this);
                String ids = layout.getChildAt(i).getResources().getResourceEntryName(layout.getChildAt(i).getId());

idss = idss + "\n" + "case: "+ "R.id." +ids;
                //Log.i(idss, "");
            }
        }
        Log.i(idss, "");
        textView.setText(idss);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       Log.i("HI", "Hey");
        switch (view.getId()){
         case R.id.playAgain:
             Log.i(idss, "");
           //  Log.i("HI", "He");
            //case

        }

    }
}
```

XML

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/finishedLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Good Job You Got \n X out of Y \n Questions Correct"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Again"
        android:id="@+id/playAgain"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Return to Start"
        android:id="@+id/returnStart"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Share Your Score"
        android:id="@+id/shareScore"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go over Missed"
        android:id="@+id/retry"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Review Statistics"
        android:id="@+id/scoreStatistics"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change Preferences"
        android:id="@+id/changePrefrences"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

It returns the first 4 ids but stops at the R. of the 5.
Also when the Log.i("Hi", "HEY") is removed it wont print out anything.
Any help figuring out what in the world is going on in this would be a great help.

```
case: R.id.playAgain
    case: R.id.returnStart
    case: R.id.shareScore
    case: R.id.retry
    case: R. at[ 07-03 19:31:14.715   755:  867 E/WifiStateMachine ]
    [1,435,966,274,715 ms] noteScanEnd WorkSource{10011} onTime=0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your tag used for logging is too long. It isn't well documented, but it has 23 character limit and there is no gurantee logging will work correctly when you exceed it.

[The logging tag can be at most 23 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters)

Comment: Yeah that is what originally thought. However I put the tag in a text editor and it 104 characters, so it seems as if that limit is no longer true, but maybe there is a new limit.