# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log tag "okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer" exceeds limit of 23 characters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, okhttp, mockwebserver

Some points to clarify that this is not a duplicate question as someone suggested:

- This is a "**runtime crash**" caused by long log tag name. i.e. `okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer`, this is **not an IDE lint error**.
- This crash is caused by a third party dependency, i.e. MockWebServer. And thanks to [Yuri Schimke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1542667/yuri-schimke) for raising a bug
  [Fix android logging with MockWebServer](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6220).
- I have provided my fix in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63388805/8034839.

---

**Original question:**

I am working on Android web service tests using `Expresso` and `MockWebServer`, however I encounter below exception that tells me the log tag issue:

> "okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer" exceeds limit of 23 characters.

Detailed stack trace is as following:

```sh
2020-08-13 11:31:13.277 16901-17085/com.xxx.app I/okhttp.OkHttpClient: <-- HTTP FAILED: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
2020-08-13 11:31:13.280 16901-17346/com.xxx.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: MockWebServer TaskRunner
    Process: com.xxx.app, PID: 16901
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Log tag "okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer" exceeds limit of 23 characters
    
        at android.util.Log.isLoggable(Native Method)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.AndroidLog.androidLog$okhttp(AndroidLog.kt:66)
        at okhttp3.internal.platform.android.AndroidLogHandler.publish(AndroidLog.kt:39)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:615)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:636)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:725)
        at okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer$serveConnection$$inlined$execute$1.runOnce(TaskQueue.kt:224)
        at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.runTask(TaskRunner.kt:116)
        at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner.access$runTask(TaskRunner.kt:42)
        at okhttp3.internal.concurrent.TaskRunner$runnable$1.run(TaskRunner.kt:65)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
2020-08-13 11:31:13.293 16901-17346/com.xxx.app I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16901 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The logging tag can be at most 23 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters)

Comment: My question is that `"okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer"` as a log tag cause the exception, and how to fix this or any workaround about this?

Comment: I've raised https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6220, we already workaround other logging name length issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out the workaround for this issue after digging into the source code of `MockWebServer.kt`. Inside this file, there is a property like below:

```kotlin
private val logger = Logger.getLogger(MockWebServer::class.java.name)
```

The `MockWebServer::class.java.name` will return a full class name `okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer`, obviously, this name as an Android log tag is already longer than 23 chars. The fix is using Kotlin reflection to replace the logger property. Reflection code is as below:

```
fun <T : Any> T.setPrivateProperty(variableName: String, data: Any): Any? {
    return javaClass.getDeclaredField(variableName).let { field ->
        field.isAccessible = true
        field.set(this, data)
        return@let field.get(this)
    }
}
```

Inside the `@before` method, set the logger tag with `simpleName`

```kotlin
val mockWebServer = MockWebServer() // this is declared inside test class.

@Before
fun setup() {

    mockWebServer.setAndReturnPrivateProperty("logger", 
        Logger.getLogger(MockWebServer::class.java.simpleName))

    mockWebServer.start(8080)
}
```

`MockWebServer::class.java.simpleName` will return a shorter class name and fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it's due to Log API doesn't allow tag that exceeds 23 characters.

You can disable the lint checking by following [Terence's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28738249/12676247), but you've been warned.

for better understanding visit :
[The logging tag can be at most 23 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters#:%7E:text=From%20Android%20Studio%27s%20Recent%20Changes,tag%20that%20exceeds%2023%20characters.)

Comment: This is not a lint phase issue, it is a runtime exception and haunt the tests from normal execution.