# How to log an object in Android Java?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to log the following in Android Java:

```java
    Log.i("Build.VERSION.SDK_INT", Build.VERSION.SDK_INT.toString());
    Log.i("Build.VERSION_CODES.M", Build.VERSION_CODES.M.toString());
    Log.i("Build.VERSION_CODES.O", Build.VERSION_CODES.O.toString());
    Log.i("getReactApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS", getReactApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS).toString());
    Log.i("getReactApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS)", getReactApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS).toString());
    Log.i("getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)", getReactApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE).toString());
    Log.i("Build.VERSION_CODES.O", Build.VERSION_CODES.O.toString());
```

But I get the error `error: int cannot be dereferenced` on every line.

How can I log these objects in logcat?

Comment: Thanks, but is every one of these values an integer? My question is how can I log these objects?

Comment: Look at the top answer to the question I referenced, it explains why you can't call methods on primitives and even gives an alternative.

Comment: There is an error: "
The logging tag can be at most 23 characters, was 86 (getReactApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28168622/the-logging-tag-can-be-at-most-23-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and other are integers. They are primitives and do not have `toString()` function.
If you want to convert `int` to `String` you can use `String.valueOf()`.

```
Log.i("Build.VERSION.SDK_INT", String.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT));
```

Or **sometimes** it is easier to use string concatenation. For example:

```
Log.i("Build.VERSION.SDK_INT", "" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT);
```

I mostly use second method for debugging purposes.